# Is a composited function Riemann-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have found a function $f\circ g$ where $f$ is Riemann-integrable and $g$ is infinitely differentiable such that $f\circ g$  is not  Riemann-integrable. However, in that case, $g$ is  not monotonous. So my question is that if $g$ is monotonous, diffrentiable, and $g'$ is Riemann-integrable, is it true that $f\circ g$ is Riemann-integrable? If not, what condition can be added to make it true?

The example are as follow:

Take a Cantor set $C\in[0,1]$ , $m(C)>0$, $g(x)=1$ when $x\in C$，make a infinitely differentiable extension by using $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ on $[0,1]\backslash C$, such that $0<g(x)<1$. Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\in[0,1),\\
1,x=1,\end{cases}$$
then $f\circ g$ is not Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Can you show us the example you have?

Comment: I have just edited the question and add the example above.

Comment: How exactly is $g$ defined?